# MySQL: How to do foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I wish to have a foreign key in a table but I have no idea how to do it. I wish have a UserID Column in the "wall" table so that I can link back and get the userid's details etc. How would i go about doing this?

Wall Table:
[alt text http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/7701/screenshot20100808at010.png](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/7701/screenshot20100808at010.png)

Users Table:
[alt text http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/7701/screenshot20100808at010.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/7701/screenshot20100808at010.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In order to have a foreign key column called `userid` in the `WALL` table, you need to create the column - skip to #2 if the column already exists:

```
ALTER TABLE WALL
  ADD COLUMN userid INT(25) NOT NULL
```

If you want to allow WALL records to exist without the userid being specified:

```
ALTER TABLE WALL
  ADD COLUMN userid INT(25) NULL
```

2) Now you [add the foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
ALTER TABLE WALL
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES USERS(userid)
```

Comment: Thanks so far, however I get "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES users(UserID)' at line 2"

When i run ALTER TABLE WALL
 ADD FOREIGN KEY userid REFERENCES USERS(userid)

Comment: @ritch: Fixed - I forgot to put brackets around the FK column name.

Comment: Put parentheses around "userId" after ADD FOREIGN KEY.  The parentheses are not optional, nor are they redundant.  You can have a foreign key that consists of multiple columns, and they'd all go inside the parentheses: (colA, colB).

Answer (score 1):

Add a UserID column to the Wall table and then create a foreign key on it.  In SQL, it'd look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Wall (
    ...
    UserID INT,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES User (UserID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note that you may not want to have ON DELETE RESTRICT.  That's the most restrictive option.  Read up about it on the MySQL website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: The OP has to drop the existing WALL table in order to use what you've provided, or rename the existing table so the new one can be created & copy data over.

Comment: I wanted to make it clear in the table structure.  I considered using the ALTER TABLE syntax, but I thought that'd make it less obvious.  Six in one, half dozen the other and all that.

Comment: +1: For demonstrating how to implement the FK in the CREATE TABLE statement